# Non periodic square function train in python

Tags: python, signals, pulse

How can I plot a square-like (non periodic) signal like the one in the image using python? with0 "n" the number of pulses, "p" the time between them, pulse duration, amplitude and "offset" as variables.

[image: Pulse train over time]

Already tried scipy.signal.square but im looking for a non periodic solution.

Comment: Aren't you also missing a parameter for "width" of each pulse? (And maybe hight and vertical offset as well?)

Comment: Yes you're right, I will edit the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing to do is to just write some custom code, instead of built-in modules like to tried. For instance:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

def plot_square_pulses(n, p, dur, amp, offset):
    plt.figure()
    for i in range(n):
        x1 = i * (p + dur) + offset
        x2 = x1 + dur
        plt.hlines(amp, x1, x2, linewidth=2)
        plt.vlines(x1, 0, amp, linewidth=2)
        plt.vlines(x2, 0, amp, linewidth=2)
    plt.axis('equal')

# Example usage:
plot_square_pulses(n=5, p=0.3, dur=1, amp=1, offset=0.2)
```

The resulting plot can probably be improved, but should put you in the right direction:

[image]